# Couchbase C API - multiple server connections

Tags: c++, couchbase

I'm writing a small application in C++ that needs to connect to a Couchbase cluster and read data from a normal Couchbase bucket as well as a Memcached bucket. I can connect and read/write data without any issues. However, when I try to create two instances of the couchbase class and connect one of the instances to the Couchbase bucket and the second to the Memcached bucket I always end up with both instances pointing to the one I connected to last. So in the following code it would be the Memcached bucket.

```
couchbase cb
couchbase cache

cb.connect(hosts, bucket)
cache.connect(hosts, bucketCache)
```

The couchbase class is a class I created to encapsulate all basic Couchbase functionality based on the documentation from the C API documentation.

As I said I can query documents in either bucket just fine if I only connect to one of the buckets. But as soon as I connect to both at the same time I only get the connection to the last one.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well I found the answer by simply moving the `lcb_t instance` from the head of the cpp file into the private section of the class header file. So it had nothing to do with Couchbase in the end but rather C++.